# ラズベリーパイにTensorflowを正しくインストールするための助言をください

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

### 理由

TensorflowとKerasを使って写真を2種類に分類する深層学習プログラムを、市販の書籍を参照して作成しました。この作成には、WindowsPCでAnacondaとJupiterNotebookを使いました。実際に2種類の写真を多くの枚数、用意し、学習データとテストデータに分け、それらを使ってWindowsPCで学習とテストを行いました。これにより、model.jsonとweight.h5が生成されました。

上記で生成されたmodel.jsonとweight.h5をラズパイに入れて、ラズパイで写真を撮影し、その写真が、2種類のうちどちらなのかをラズパイで即座に判定させたい。

### 環境

- ラズパイのバージョン　3b+
- debianのバージョン10.4
- Python　ラズパイにもともと3.7.3がインストール済み
- pip　ラズパイにインストール済みのpip18.1を20.1.1にアップデートした

### 行った作業とその結果

Tensorflowのホームページ（下記）に従って準備とインストール作業を行った。
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

- 手順のうち、OSによって使うコマンドが違う箇所は、次のほうを選択した。
- SUDOコマンドは[Raspberry Pi]の記述に倣った。
- 仮想環境の作成は[Ubuntu/Mac OS]のうち「# sh, bash, or zsh」の場合の記述に倣った。
- 仮想環境をvirtualenvで作成した。
- 仮想環境ではラズパイにインストール済みのPython3.7.3を使用。
- 仮想環境でのpipを20.1.1とした。
- 仮想環境に入り、Tensorflowをpipでインストールしようとした。
- 途中下記のような2回のwarningが表示されたが、インストール自体は最後まで進んだ。

  ```
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/protobuf/

  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/h5py/
  ```
- しかし、ホームページに書かれた「Verify the install」

  ```
  $ python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
  ```

  をすると、

  ```
  2020-06-08 01:31:57.302837: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```

  と表示された。
- 仮想環境で`pip freeze`とすると、リストの中に

  ```
  tensorflow==1.14.0
  tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
  ```

  が表示された。（ホームページによるとバージョン2がインストールされるらしいが、なぜか1.14.0である）
- 仮想環境でPythonを立ち上げ、importを試みたところ、

  ```
  import numpy as np
  ```

  はうまくいくが、

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf
  ```

  と入力すると、次のようなエラーメッセージが表示された。

  ```
  2020-06-08 08:45:48.118904: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```

（説明は以上です。）

Comment: RasPi には詳しくないのでコメントに留めますが、こちらの記事がさんこうになるかかもしれません。 - [Pythonおよび機械学習勉強用のRaspberryPiの構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/rhene/items/d370a3b3f05a7248bd79)

Comment: cubick様が紹介された記事の末尾に「 @PINTO 氏がビルド済みのパッケージを公開しています」とのリンクが載っています。その@PINTO 氏の記事を読んでパッケージをインストールしたところ、（途中で関連パッケージのインストールに試行錯誤しましたが）無事Tensorflowをインストールできました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 少しはお役に立てたようでなによりです。もし良ければご自身で解決に至った手順を **個別の回答** として投稿してもらうと、同じ様な問題で困った人の助けになると思います。[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) も歓迎ですので、ぜひけんとうしてみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

【自己回答】
頂いたコメントをもとに取り組んだところ，下記の方法でインストールできました。

github.com の PINTO0309氏のページ
https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/blob/master/README.md
を参照しました。
このページの解説に沿い、自分のラズパイの条件を確認し、インストールすべきwhlファイルを決めた上で、このページ中の「Usage」に沿って実行しました。
（質問では、仮想環境へインストールできない、と書きましたが、今回はとにかくインストールが正常終了すればよし、という方針を採り、仮想環境を使わずにインストールしました。）

以下に、実行したコマンドを記します。
$のあとに記すのは、ターミナル画面で入力したコマンド。
その次の行は、応答。（応答は要点のみ示す）
(py3>)のあとに記すのは、ターミナル画面でpython3実行中に入力したコマンド。

◆debianのバージョン確認
$ cat /etc/debian_version
10.4

◆ラズパイのバージョン確認
$ lsb_release -a
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

◆Pythonのバージョン確認
$ python3
Python 3.7.3

◆CPUアーキテクチャーの確認
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)

◆gcc（GNUプロジェクトが開発・公開しているコンパイラ）のバージョン確認
$ gcc --version
gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0

◆ldd（共有ライブラリへの依存関係を表示するコマンド）のバージョン確認
$ ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+rpi1) 2.28

◆PINTO0309氏のページ中の「Usage　Example of Python 3.x + Tensorflow v1 series」に沿って、以下を実行しました。
$ sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libc-ares-dev libeigen3-dev gcc gfortran python-dev libgfortran5 
libatlas3-base libatlas-base-dev libopenblas-dev libopenblas-base libblas-dev 
liblapack-dev cython openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev libatlas-base-dev python3-dev

$ sudo pip3 install keras_applications==1.0.8 --no-deps

$ sudo pip3 install keras_preprocessing==1.1.0 --no-deps

$ sudo pip3 install h5py==2.9.0

$ sudo pip3 install pybind11

$ pip3 install -U --user six wheel mock

$ sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow
WARNING: Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.

$ wget https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/raw/master/tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl

$ sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
◆（途中、次の2つのエラーが発生）
ERROR: tensorboard 1.15.0 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.8.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: protobuf, grpcio, wrapt, absl-py, termcolor, zipp, importlib-metadata, markdown, tensorboard, google-pasta, opt-einsum, tensorflow-estimator, astor, gast, tensorflow

Attempting uninstall: wrapt
Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

◆そこで、setuptoolsをダウンロード
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/95/f657b6e17f00c3f35b5f68b10e46c3a43af353d8856bd57bfcfb1dbb3e92/setuptools-47.1.1-py3-none-any.whl

◆setuptoolsをインストール
$ sudo pip3 install setuptools-47.1.1-py3-none-any.whl

◆wraptのバージョンを確認
$ pip3 show wrapt
Name: wrapt
Version: 1.10.11

◆wraptをインストール
$ sudo pip3 install -I wrapt
Collecting wrapt
Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/wrapt/wrapt-1.12.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl (68 kB)
Installing collected packages: wrapt
Successfully installed wrapt-1.12.1

◆tensorflowをインストール
$ sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
Successfully installed tensorflow-1.15.0

$ python3
◆種々のパッケージのインポート
◆（下記の各インポートは、成功）
(py3>) from tensorflow import keras
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
(py3>) import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

◆（下記のインポートは、失敗）
(py3>) from tensorflow.keras.utils import np_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'np_utils' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/api/_v1/keras/utils/**init**.py)

◆np_utilsのインストール
$ sudo pip3 install np_utils
Successfully installed future-0.18.2 np-utils-0.5.12.1

$ python3
◆パッケージのインポート
◆（下記のインポートは、成功）
(py3>) import np_utils

◆以上でインストール作業を完了。

Answer (score 0):

現状 Tensorflow がサポートしている OS は Ubuntu、macOS、Windows、Raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS) のみで Debian はサポートされていません。参照なさったページに書かれている手順も Raspbian が想定されており、Debian ではありません。このためどこかで齟齬が発生している可能性があります。

手元で試していませんが、たとえば arm32 向けの wheel を公開している https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm を使って以下のようにインストールすると上手くいかないでしょうか。

```
curl -O https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v2.2.0/tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
pip install --upgrade ./tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

Comment: 助言ありがとうございます。最初に上記cubick様のコメントを手がかりとしてインストールに取り組んだところ、成功しました。そのためご教示いただいたlhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm  は私も未試行ですが、nekketsuuu様のいう、CPUやOSの条件を確かめてwheelを使うという方針、それは適切だということが分かりました。